# Upgrade from smarty 2 to 3 Unexpected "|"

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, smarty2, smarty-plugins

I am sorting out issues in a smarty upgrade from 2 to 3 and I am getting this error and I can't figure out why:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
> {$item.content_group_name | htmlspecialchars} - Unexpected "|"

Anyone have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smarty 3 fails with that error if there is white space around the | character when declaring a modifier. Change your tag to

```
{$item.content_group_name|htmlspecialchars}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27224159)

Comment: It does answer the question actually, but I will update my answer to be more verbose.

Comment: Thank you. You nailed it. It's funny I had suspected that was the issue but didn't notice in my test the error line number had changed. Cheers!